# What is Akamai Ghost?

Tags: firewalls, dns

After making requests to certain domain and their responses being either 4xx or 5xx status codes, the server response header shows Akamai Ghost.

**Is this response coming from Akamai's firewall or their CDN servers?**

Comment: Please include some of the responses you got.

Answer (score 2):

Per an answer to a post on the Akamai Community site:

> AkamaiGhost stands for Akamai Global Host (also known as Edge Server, or Edge node)

Based on the information provided and the definition, I'd say this is a CDN server.

The video in the references shows examples of using `cURL` to troubleshoot.
The cache server it's hitting are Akamai GHost's.

**References**
[Akamai Community Question](https://community.akamai.com/customers/s/question/0D50f00005RtpdZCAR/akamaighost?language=en_US)
[Using cURL to Troubleshoot Akamai Requests](https://youtu.be/uIu2TbdDoKY)